# Select a CheckBox from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ActiveX CheckBox control on worksheet "A" and another on worksheet "B". When I check the CheckBox at "A", I want my macro to check the CheckBox at "B".

What I have tried so far:

[This](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147272): `Sheets("B").Shapes("CheckBox1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn`

[And this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741836/checking-if-a-worksheet-based-checkbox-is-checked): `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1`

Both codes give me an error saying that the the object doesn't accept this property or method.

So it's not possible to check a CheckBox from another worksheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkbox1 in sheet 1 to change checkbox1 in sheet 2

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1 = True Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").CheckBox1.Value = True
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet2").CheckBox1.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

I find it useful to use a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to reference a worksheet as it allows multiple operations.

```
With Worksheets("B")
    ' for Form Control Checkbox
    .Shapes("Check Box 2").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
    ' for ActiveX Control Checkbox
    .Shapes("CheckBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = xlOn
End With
```

The prefix period (aka `.` or *full stop*) applies the parent worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

> For me, replacing the numbers 1 and 0 as for, respectively, the
>   boolean "True" and "False" did not work. Some say that ActivexControl
>   has "False" equal to -4146 and FormControl has "False" as equal to 0. This did not work either. The snipped below is now working.

```
Dim i as Integer

For i = 1 to 502

  If Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Alpha-" & i).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then '<-- FormControl

    Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("beta" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = 1 '<--ActivexControl
  Else
     Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("beta" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = 0 '<--ActivexControl
  End If

next i
```